# Finding the limit of a rational function at its vertical asymptote

Tags: calculus

Find the limit as x approaches 15 from the right of the function (x minus 9)/(negative x+15)

I know the limit is supposed to be negative infinity; however, I don't know how to prove this algebraically. I always get zero in the denominator when I try to use Fermat's difference quotient or finding the derivative using the quotient rule.

Comment: IS it you mean $f(x)=\dfrac{x-9}{-x+15}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The numerator approaches 6, and as x approaches 15, the denominator approaches zero from the negative side.

This would give the function a "limit" of negative infinity, whereas had it approached zero from the positive side, it would've given a limit of positive infinity.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to 15^{+}}\dfrac{x-9 }{-x+15}=-\infty\\$$you want to show it by definition $$
\forall N>0  \space \exists \space \delta >0 : 0<x-15<\delta \Rightarrow f(x)<-N$$
$$0<x-15<\delta  \to 15<x<15+\delta \\6<x-9<6+\delta \\\dfrac{x-9 }{-x+15}<-N \to 
 \times (-1)\\\dfrac{x-9 }{x-15}>+N\\
\dfrac{x-15}{x-9}<\dfrac{1}{N} \\x-15 <\dfrac{x-9}{N}<\dfrac{6+\delta}{N}<\dfrac{7}{N} \\\to $$so you can take $$\delta <\dfrac{7}{N}$$
can you take it over  ?